# How to get a random order on a array.orderby C#

Tags: c#, arrays, .net

I am trying to find the nearest integer to a set integer from an array but want to pick a random one if there is more than one.

`var nearestScore = scoreArray.OrderBy(x => Math.Abs((long)x - realScore)).First();`

I don't know any other way but using `First()`.

I have also tried

```
var r = new random()
var nearestScore = scoreArray.OrderBy(x => Math.Abs((long)x - realScore)).ToArray();
return nearestScore[r.next(0, nearestScore.Length - 1)]
```

Thanks.

Comment: need more clarification

Comment: This makes no sense. If your input is 100, and there are 97, 98, and 99 in an array, 99 is the **only** number that will be closest. And if there are duplicate entries of 99, why would you need to pick a random one?

Comment: [C#: Elegant code for getting a random value from an IEnumerable](//stackoverflow.com/q/7258824)

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne If the input is `98` and the values are `99` and `97`, there are two "nearest" values.

Comment: Good point @RufusL

Comment: Why are you casting to `long` if the types are all `int`?

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne as the whole point of the program is to give winners. real score being what they need to guess. giving the names in an other array too

Answer (score 0):

You can add an Extension FirstEqual:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FirstEqual<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{

      var e = source.GetEnumerator();
      if (e.MoveNext())
      {

          T first = e.Current;
          yield return first;
          while (e.MoveNext())
          {

             if (e.Current.Equals(first))
                yield return first;
              else 
                 break;
          }

      }
}
```

and than you call

`scoreArray.OrderBy(x => Math.Abs((long)x - realScore)).FirstEqual()`

This will return you a collection of equal numbers.

We could also return a Tuple of the first number and its Count.

Comment: Just cast out of index exception. Like I got at the bottom of my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `GroupBy()` for this. It's a little heavy-handed but simple for small arrays.

```
Random rnd = new Random();

var nearestScore = scoreArray
    .Select(x => new { Num = x, Delta = Math.Abs((long)x - realScore)) })
    .OrderBy(a => a.Delta)
    .GroupBy(a => a.Delta)
    .First()
    .OrderBy(a => rnd.Next())
    .Select(a => a.Num)
    .First();
```

Comment: Every time you order by `rnd.Next()`, someone strangles a puppy.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: Is there a technique you prefer for generating a random permutation fairly?

Comment: It would be better practice to group *first* and then sort by the group key; that way you are sorting *a small set of groups* rather than *a large set of items*.

Comment: @EricLippert I would take the values from the whole first group into a list or array and either shuffle it to take the first item or take the value from a random index. Or maybe just take the first unshuffled item; you can't prove it's _not_ random ;)

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: The stated premise of the question is that "take the first item" is insufficiently random. It's not clear to me that your proposed solution is much better; wouldn't it be better still to say "take the minimal group into a list and take a random item"?  What benefit does shuffling the elements you are *not* going to choose add in your proposal?

Comment: @EricLippert The first version of the comment wasn't as clear. It's been edited to basically do that. But mainly, my understanding is ordering by rnd.Next() has a small (winning the lottery small, but still) chance of not finishing or causing an exception. You could also select into a new anonymous object with fields for the original type and a random value, and order by the extra field, but that's awkward, too.

Comment: There will only ever be one or two items in the first group. Does it really help to create a list and shuffle it?

Comment: @itsme86 what is delta? int does not contain definition delta. im confused. ive got `var nearestScore = scoreArray.OrderBy(x => Math.Abs((long)x - realScore)).GroupBy(a => a.Delta);`

Comment: @RufusL: That's only true because the metric in the question is "closeness of an integer to another integer", and there are only ever two integers that are equally close to a third. But suppose the original poster, or someone else, then wishes to adapt the solution to "closeness of a string to another string by edit distance", and now it is possible that there is any number of "ties".

Comment: @EarthMonster `Delta` is defined in the first `Select` statement as a property of the anonymous type being selected.

Comment: @RufusL: or "closeness of a set of points (in any space of strictly more than one dimension) to a center point".  Or "edit distance of an abstract syntax tree to a particular code sample". You get the idea. We can make arbitrarily complex versions of this problem all day, and they are realistic; I have myself recently had to solve a problem very similar to that of tiebreaking amongst different syntax trees with similarity to a given code sample as the metric.

Comment: @EricLippert Sure, I understand, but the statement was **Every time** you order by `rnd.Next()` a puppy gets strangled. Was wondering if that really applies to this case.

Comment: @RufusL what do you mean? i am quite new to coding. this is my first project with arrays

Comment: @EarthMonster Look at the code in the answer. The `Select` statement is selecting an anonymous type, where a property named `Num` represents the integer and a property named `Delta` represents it's distance from `realScore`.

Comment: @RufusL im using the groupby

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn:  You said "*But mainly, my understanding is ordering by rnd.Next() has a small (winning the lottery small, but still) chance of not finishing or causing an exception.*" You are misremembering. It is always safe to OrderBy a random value. OrderBy does the equivalent of creating an array of values and an array of keys, and then sorting the array of values by the keys. What you are probably thinking of is that it is always *wrong* to attempt a shuffle by making a *comparator* that randomly decides whether X is bigger, equal to, or smaller than Y.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: The reason that is always wrong is that a comparator is *required* to follow rules: X is always equal to X, if X is smaller than Y then Y is greater than X, and there must never be a transitivity paradox; that is if X is smaller than Y and Y is smaller than Z, then X must be smaller than Z. A random comparator does not meet this contract and can cause a sort algorithm to fail in arbitrarily bad ways.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: There are issues with ordering by Random.Next, but they are not that the sort itself will go poorly. Rather, it is that *it is possible to determine the seed that was used from only a small sample of a list sorted in this manner*, and once you have the seed, you know the order of the entire list, not just your portion of it.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: Moreover, sorting by Random.Next is not *fair*, in the sense that the number of observed permutations is a function of the entropy of the seed, which is smaller than the number of theoretically possible permutations once you are sorting more than a couple dozen objects. You can therefore know that certain permutations are impossible, which gives you unfair knowledge of the possible states of the system.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: A common bad pattern I see is ordering by `new Guid()`. This is bad because, though version 4 guids are documented as being random, they are not documented as being random with any particular amount of entropy, and nor are they documented as being produced in any particular order. An implementation of `new Guid()` would be justified in producing *sequential* guids, for example, which obviously would not lead to a shuffled list. Guids are documented as being unique, and that is the only of their properties that should be relied upon.

Comment: @EricLippert: `new Guid()` returns `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`.  I assume you mean `Guid.NewGuid()`.

Answer (score 0):

Brake it in few statements:

```
var minScore = scoreArray.Min(x => Math.Abs((long)x - realScore));
var list = scoreArray.Where(x => Math.Abs((long)x - realScore) == minScore).ToList();
// or you can use GroupBy with OrderBy and First instead of above, but this is lighter and cleaner
r = new Random();
var myRandomNumber = r.Next(0, list.Count);
return list[myRandomNumber];
```

Comment: I cannot do this because later in the code, I have to do this: `int indexWinner = Array.IndexOf(scoreArray, nearestScore);`

Comment: FYI, you don't need to subtract `1` since the `maxValue` argument is exclusive, and I think you mean to select the index from `list`, not `scoreArray`. You can simplify by replacing the last 3 lines with with `return list[new Random().Next(list.Count)];`

Comment: Corrected the `-1` and `list' - thanks! and I agree it could be simplified, but I leave as is for clarity.